# Space delimited file into structure array C

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I would like to store information from file in structure. My file consists of rows (each row has to be different structure) and columns, each column is different data. File looks like this:

```
1 AB
2 CD
3 CD
4 AB
```

My structure is this (where node number is first integer and node type is two letter):

```
struct nodes{
int nodeNumber;
char nodeType[2];
};
```

My code so far is this:

```
lines = lineCount(nodes); //calculates how many lines file has
struct nodes node[lines]; //creates structure array
no = fopen(nodes, mode);
if(no == NULL){
    printf("Can't find the files.");
    exit(1);
}else{
    for(i = 0; i < lines; i++){
        fscanf(no, "%d %2c \n", &id, current);
        node[i].nodeNumber = id;
        strcpy(node[i].nodeType, current);
    }
}
```

when i debug current value is this: current = \"AB\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\" rather than just AB

any ideas?

Comment: how is `current` declared?  What you are seeing just looks like there are nul bytes in the character buffer.  Nothing to worry about since in C, nul bytes indicate the end of a string.  Also note that `strcpy` will try to put a nul byte on the end of your `nodeType`, which will overflow the buffer.

Comment: I resolved my problem it wasnt even in the code i included. Thanks for help tho!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your use of `strcpy`. It copies *string*, i.e. character arrays with a terminator. This means that `strcpy` will copy until it sees the string terminator character `'\0'` *and* put that at the end of the array, which means you will overwrite one byte outside of the array.

Either use manual copying character by character, a function such as [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy), or increase the size of the array to three so it can fit the terminating character (which means you have to make sure the definition of `current` is also of size three, with a string terminator).

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` does not nul-terminate characters read with the `%c` format code. (Although apparently `current` has lots of NULs, I don't know if you can count on that.

You should declare `current` as `char[2]`, and use `memcpy` with a length of 2 instead of `strcpy`.